# How to calculate this integral with exponential?

Tags: calculus

How to calculate this integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} \; \mathrm dx$$

Comment: What have you done so far? Any thoughts on how might tackle it?

Comment: Should the lower bounds be negative...

Comment: You sure there is no typo? Also have you heard of differentiating under the integral sign?

Comment: Soryy I made a mistake @Chinny84

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: we have the Gaussian integral:

$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}\ dx=\sqrt{\frac\pi t}$$

We then have

$$-f'(1/2)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2e^{-\frac12x^2}\ dx=\dots$$

Can you finish the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write,

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx>0$$

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2} dy$$

So that,

$$I^2=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} x^2y^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)} dA$$

Converting to polar we have,

$$I^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} r^5\cos^2 (\theta) \sin^2 (\theta)e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} dr d \theta$$

$$I^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2 (\theta) \sin^2 (\theta) d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty} r^5e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} dr$$

$$I^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4} \sin^2 (2\theta) d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty}  r^5e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} dr$$

On the second integral try $u=r^2$ and integration by parts. Or $u=\frac{1}{2}r^2$ and remember the integral form of the gamma function.

Comment: Good 'ole fashion polar methods.  :-)

Comment: how did you get from first set of equations to the third ?

Comment: @Chinny84 are you familiar with polar transformations?  That's all this is.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yup I am. But Ahmed had $$\int (x^2+y^2)\mathrm{e}^{\alpha(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$ rather than $$\int (x^2y^2)\mathrm{e}^{\alpha(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$ which he has now.

Comment: Sorry. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac{1}{2}x^2=u$ then 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} \; \mathrm dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty} 2u \mathrm e^{-u} \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{2u}}=2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} u^\frac12 \mathrm e^{-u} du=2\sqrt{2}\Gamma(\frac32)=\sqrt{2\pi}$$